# Как сделать плавное приближение к объекту(AS3)

Tags: actionscript

Имеется такой код

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, wheel, false, 0, true);
private function wheel(evt:MouseEvent):void{
    if (evt.delta < 0)
    {
        controller.distance *= 1.10;
    }
    else
    {
        controller.distance /= 1.1;
    }
    return;/
}
```

С его помощью - осуществляется простое приближение камеры к объекту, но оно не плавное как [тут](http://blog.project-nya.jp/1991) - при вращении, а с "прерываниями". Не могу понять как используя controller, - который делает вращение камеры плавным, сделать тоже самое для приближения.

В принципе я пробовал написать что-то подобное - проверки

```
if (zoomOverTimeFactor > 0) {
    (zoomOverTimeFactor - 1);
    //zoomin=true;

    if (zoomOverTimeFactor > 0) {
        controller.distance -= zoomOverTimeFactor * zoomOverTimeCameraFactor;

    } else {
        zoomOverTimeFactor = 0;
    }

}
if (zoomOverTimeFactor < 0) {
    (zoomOverTimeFactor + 1);

    if (zoomOverTimeFactor < 0) {
        controller.distance -= zoomOverTimeFactor * zoomOverTimeCameraFactor;

    } else {
        zoomOverTimeFactor = 0;
    }
}
private
function wheel(evt: MouseEvent): void {

    if (evt.delta < 0) {

        //controller.distance *= 1.10;
        zoomOverTimeFactor = -10;

    } else {
        //controller.distance /= 1.1;
        zoomOverTimeFactor = 10;
        //zoomin = true


    }
    //return;

}
```

Но результат - получилось не совсем правильным, ибо приближение и отдаление от объекта становиться - бесконечным, то есть постоянным, не пойму как сделать проверку - если значение приближения увеличилось - то прекратить движение, и на -оборот

Answer (score 1):

Блиннн, промучался еще пару минут и удалось с гов*о-кодить вот такой костыль.

```
            if (zoomOverTimeFactor > 0 )
        {
            (zoomOverTimeFactor - 1);
            //zoomin=true;

            if (zoomOverTimeFactor > 0)
            {
                controller.distance -=  zoomOverTimeFactor * zoomOverTimeCameraFactor;
                if(controller.distance >0)// Фикс начинается 
                    zoomOverTimeFactor /= 1.1; //тут
            }
            else
            {
                zoomOverTimeFactor = 0;
            }

        }
```

Мож кому понадобиться =) я хз конечно, но буду - не против если кто-то сможет предложить нормальное решение ?